# Django generic detail view must be called with an object pk or a slug but my URL has a PK already

Tags: python, django

AttributeError at /mini_fb/profile/1/delete_status/14
Generic detail view DeleteStatusMessageView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

Isn't my PK 1 and 14 already in the URL? Why am I getting this error?

```
<a href="{% url 'delete_status' profile_pk=profile.pk status_pk=x.pk %}">delete</a>
```

```
class DeleteStatusMessageView(DeleteView):
    '''A class for the view for deleting status messages.'''

    template_name = 'mini_fb/delete_status_message.html'
    queryset = StatusMessage.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        '''Return a dictionary with context data for this template to use.'''

        context = super(DeleteStatusMessageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        st_msg = StatusMessage.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['status_pk'])
        context['st_msg'] = st_msg

        return context # return the dictionary
```

Comment: show us your urlconf

Comment: ```path('profile/<int:profile_pk>/delete_status/<int:status_pk>', DeleteStatusMessageView.as_view(), name='delete_status'),```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DeleteView parameter should be named exactly pk or slug

```
path('profile/<int:profile_pk>/delete_status/<int:pk>', DeleteStatusMessageView.as_view(), name='delete_status')
```

You could set `pk_url_kwarg` if you would like to override default name ( [SingleObjectMixin docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#singleobjectmixin))

Comment: This fixed it for me. Why can I have a custom PK name for the first argument but not the second?